# How to hide element based on value contains?

Tags: jquery, input, hide

I'm trying to hide a button if it contains the value 'foo'.

The code below isn't working and I cant see why:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Example</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("button:contains('foo')").parent('div').hide();
  });
</script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="prod_buy">
    <input name="Add to Cart" type="submit" class="rb green txtbutton" value="foo">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[value=foo]").closest('div').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you aren't matching a button, it's a submit input.

Use something like this:

```
$("input[type=submit][value*=foo]").parent('div').hide();
```

The `value*` means that it will match like 'contains' e.g. it will match a button called 'foobar'.  See here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/e4ar9/